# How to delete an element from a DynamoDB List in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

[here is the image of data in dynamodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Zu1.png)

i want to delete the element from the favRest and i will have to give the value only and it sould do that here is my lambda function

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'us-east-1' });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const params = {
        TableName : 'User',
        Key:{
            "id": event.user_id,
        },
        UpdateExpression: "DELETE favRest :p",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':p': event.place_id
        },
        ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW" 
    }

    // TODO: Implementation...

    docClient.update(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Unable to update item. Error: " + err.message);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log("UpdateItem succeeded.");
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

However, it's giving me the following error:

```
"{\n  \"message\": \"Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: DELETE, operand type: STRING\",\n  \"code\": \"ValidationException\",\n  \"time\": \"2018-04-29T18:49:58.628Z\",\n  \"requestId\": \"7TDRI4TOF9S71OUJDEKMIOA40RVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG\",\n  \"statusCode\": 400,\n  \"retryable\": false,\n  \"retryDelay\": 35.34160854636804\n}"
```

what should i have to do

Answer (score 2):

The `DELETE` action only supports `Set` data types. Your `favRest` attribute type is `List`.

If you want to keep your `favRest` attribute type as `List`, you could either use `REMOVE` to delete individual elements from the list (knowing the index of the element):

```
UpdateExpression: "REMOVE favRest[:index]"
```

or you could use `SET` to replace the whole list with new values:

```
UpdateExpression: "SET favRest = :newList"
```

Otherwise, you could change `favRest` attribute type to `Set`.

See [Update Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html).